# Regular expression which accept the double quotes only and only if it follows a backslash

Tags: java, regex

How to make the regular expression for the string which accept

1. the double quotes only and only if it follows a backslash
2. if there is odd number of backslash then the last backslash should contain the special characters or any literal or any alphabets

Examples:-
The regex should not accept the following

```
"""
"\"
"\\\"
```

The regex should accept the following

```
"\""
"\r"
"\ "  here the single backslash is having space after it so it is should be accepted.
"\\"
"\\\cloud"
"\\\ "
"clo$d"
"cloud space"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your examples contain `"` at start and end. Are they part of text which will be handled by regex, for instance does `"\\"` represent 4 characters, or 2 characters (if we skip `"`), or maybe 1 character (if we skip `"` and consider ``\\`` as ``\`` literal)? If `"` indicates start and end of string literal then consider removing them from examples to avoid confusion. Instead post text which string *represents*.

Comment: ^\\[^A-Za-z0-9]$|^\\[A-Za-z0-9]$ I tried this but it didn't work

Comment: are your example strings excaped or not? because in java `"\n"` would result in a new line where as `"\\n"` would result in a string `\n`

Comment: start and end double quotes are the part of the text, it is not the part of the regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look really ugly in Java with escaping backslash for Java and for REGEX:

```
static String REGEX = "([^\"\\\\]|\\\\[^\\\\]+|\\\\\\\\)+";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    test("\"");
    test("\\");
    test("\\\\\\");
    System.out.println();
    test("\\\"");
    test("\\r");
    test("\\ ");
    test("\\\\\\cloud");
    test("\\\\\\ ");
    test("clo$d");
    test("cloud space");
}

public static void test(String s) {
    System.out.println(s + ": " + REGEX + " " + Pattern.matches(REGEX, s));
}
```